# How can I convert an angular project into a war file?

Tags: angular, tomcat, war

I am building an angular project in visual code and I want to create a war file that I can upload to tomcat 9 and deploy. Please explain it to me like I am 5.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Very good question.

**step 1.**

In `./src` folder of angular application, create a folder `WEB-INF` and create a `web.xml` file and add the below code. It helps to avoid the resource not found issue while reloading the hosted angular application.
**(It is must for Tomcat server.)**

```
<web-app>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/index.html</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

**step 2.**

Register the `WEB-INF` folder in assets array of `angular.json` file. It helps us to copy in the dist folder while taking angular build.

```
    "assets": [
      ...........,
      ...........,
      "src/WEB-INF"
     ]
```

**step 3.**

Take prod build as below. It will generate the dist folder in the root of the angular application.

```
ng build --prod --aot --base-href=/<tomcat-application-server-folder-name>/"
```

**step 4.**

Goto path `dist/<AngularApp>`,  run the command `jar cvf <tomcat-application-server-folder-name>.war .`

here dot (.) is very important in the above command. `jar cvf <tomcat-application-server-folder-name>.war .`

thats it.

if you are able follow above instructions, you can get the generated war file of angular build  in the folder `dist/<AngularApp>` with name `<tomcat-application-server-folder-name>.war`

Comment: greate explaination. I followed your introduction and it work